# Webhook With PowerShell Discord

Tags: powershell

I am getting an error while using this code

```
   $hookUrl = 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/977171177120358412/U8T5Nv5BDCOL70IeXyPjA8Vlxo-4BB2b6QXhG0nAwD_gsw2AHXCSbbcjmiFvLlFFZD6I'
    
    $content = @"
    You can enter your message content here.
    
    With a here-string, new lines are included as well!
    
    Enjoy.
    "@
    
    $payload = [PSCustomObject]@{
    
        content = $content
    
    }
    
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $hookUrl -Method Post -Body ($payload | ConvertTo-Json)
```

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}
At line:17 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $hookUrl -Method Post -Body ($payload | Conver ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I have no idea where I made a mistake, I would be glad if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Invoke-restmethod -Uri $hookUrl -Method Post -Body ($payload | ConvertTo-Json) -Headers @{ "Content-Type" = "application/json" }
```

This seems to work